# Extra counter in loop without counter = counter + 1

Tags: python, pandas

ist it possible to count in loop with a command. I found enumerate but i dont know if this is right and how to use.

```
data = np.random.randint(1,5,(5,5))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Q', 'W', 'E', 'R','Z']) 
df = df.stack()
z=0
for i in df:
    if i == 2:
        b =df.index.get_level_values(1)[z]
        print(b)
    z = z + 1
```

Comment: Well, a counter will need to change its value, e. g. by being incremented. If you don't do this, it's not a counter. Using a for-loop on a range of numbers, the for-loop increments on every iteration. If you use anything else, make sure your counter gets incremented - to me, `counter = counter+1` (similar to `counter += 1` ) is a valid way to do this.

Comment: `counter += 1`is new for me. Actually i thought that enumarate is better than to make a own counter. I think i will prefer `counter += 1` Than you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Enumerate like this:

```
for index, value in Enumerate(df):
    if value == 2:
        b = df.index.get_level_values(1)[index]
        print(b)
    print("loop index", index)
```

Think of `Enumerate` as a traditional for-loop. C

```
for(int i= 0; i < df.length; i++)
{
     // Here you have your counter `i`.
     // But you don't have the value.
     // So in order to get the value, you need to do df[i].
}
```

What Enumerate does, is that it gives you both the value, and the index of that value at the same time.

So in the example above, it gives you both `i` and `df[i]` where `index = i` and `value = df[i]`.

*Whats the benefit*? You don't have to access the value through the index like this: `df[i]`, instead you can resort to using `value`.

If english isn't your first language, *to enumerate* over something is *to go through it*.

Comment: Ty for your help. Actually i dont understand the command enumerate. Is it now counting the size like len? The documentation is confusing me.

Comment: I elaborated somewhat on Enumerate, hopefully it makes sense to you.